# Snap face to grid

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow, edit-mode, snapping

I need to move an entire object, so that one of the faces is exactly at Z=0. What is the best way to do this? Basically, if I could select Grid or 3D Cursor in the Snap To menu, that would be perfect:

[image: Imgur]

My current workaround is to select the face, copy its Z coordinate, select all, move it all down by that same amount. Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can snap to the grid or the cursor by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, however I'm not sure that is the fastest way in this case.

## Method 1

Transform snapping and a guiding plane.

1. Add a plane underneath the object
2. Enable *Face Snapping*:

   [image]
3. Press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> with the object selected and your cursor over the plane:

   [image]

**Pros**:

- Works in object mode and edit mode

**Cons**:

- Requires a new object.
- May require positioning/snapping the 3D cursor (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>) before hand (to make sure the plane is in the right place).

## Method 2

Positioning and snapping to the 3D cursor with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>.

1. Snap cursor to face (select face in edit mode and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>*> Cursor to Selected*)
2. Snap the object origin to the 3D cursor (switch to object mode and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>*> Origin to Cursor*)
3. Snap the 3D cursor to where you want the face to go (if you want it to go straight down, you can set the Z position of the cursor in *3D view > Tool Shelf (<kbd>N</kbd>) > 3D cursor*. In the gif I snapped it to the center with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, however it's slightly fewer clicks to use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>. Note that <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> will also center the view between all visible objects)
4. Snap the object to cursor (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>*> Selected to cursor*)

[image]

**Cons**:

- Requires repositioning of object origin
- Only works in object mode (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> works based on the pivot point, so in this case the center of the object would be snapped to the cursor)

## Method 3

Snap to grid with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, then increment snap to align with the gird floor.

Note that *Snap to Grid* will snap to a 3D grid, not the grid floor (though the grid floor is a 2D representation of the same grid which is used for snapping)

[image]

**Cons**:

- Will snap object to align with grid on X and Y as well.

Comment: For method 3 you can hold CTRL key to snap on grid while moving the object.

Comment: @Polosson That's actually what I did (you'll notice that the snapping/magnet icon is disabled). Holding `Ctrl` actually uses the current snapping mode (at least with transform operators), which was set to *Face* until I set it back to *Increment* (the default).

Answer (score 6):

You can enable and use the [*Drop to Ground* addon](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Object/Drop_to_ground), it's under the *Testing* category. After, that just select the object then the ground plane and press *Drop to Ground*. No need to change your object centers or any cumbersome tricks with the *3d cursor*.

[image]