# align objects on a surface

Tags: modeling

I got two cube objects I want two align their bottom to be on one surface , like they are buildings on the ground. i dont want to change objects center 
[image]

Comment: Please see this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8328/snap-face-to-grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use vertex snapping.

[image]

Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> when moving your objects to activate it.

[image]

Comment: i dont get it , can you do it with this screen guids that shows what you are doing

Comment: Hold down `Z` to move it only vertically