# How can I lay down an object on a plane?

Tags: modeling, objects

I am creating a scene with different objects scattered around, as if they were laid down on the floor, and I found that one of my objects it not touching the plane (the monkey head in the back).

[image]

So I have to move really up close to the object (then at some point the zoom strength slows down, not sure why), spin the scene around so as to be have my view aligned with the plane, then move it little by little.

[image]

[image]

But it's a Monkey head, so there's the jaw part, and there's the back of the head.
So after I align the jaw, I see that the back of the head isn't laid down on the plane, just the jaw is.

[image]

So I rotate, grab the object up on the Z axis... then the jaw isn't touching anymore...

And then I thought "wait, there's got to be a simpler way to do this".

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8328/snap-face-to-grid , http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/22888/how-to-place-any-object-on-the-floor-of-a-scene

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One solution is to use Blender's **rigid body physics** simulation. Basically, you simulate the object falling and settling on the floor from gravity.

In the *Properties > Physics* panel, turn on both *Collision* and *Rigid Body* for both your floor object and the object you want to lay down.

[image]

For the floor object, change the rigid body Type to *Passive*.

[image]

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to animate the physics simulation. You should see object fall down to the floor and eventually come to rest. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> again to stop the animation. If you want to apply the final position to all frames, select the object and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>>*Visual Transform*, then turn off the physics for those objects in the *Physics* panel.

Comment: Depending on your object, you may need to use "Mesh" as a collision shape in the rigid body settings.

Comment: @Gwenn your answer is great, thanks a lot. Not only easy to do, but also fun to look at as it happens.