# Snap object to another one with a displace modifier

Tags: snapping

I would like to snap a person i've created with the ground (in a room). I've used a displace modifier for the latter one. It's very inconvenient to do it manually by zooming in ti the max. and then to adjust them. So it's way easier to use the snap elements (faces). But how can i snap the person to the ground?

Comment: possibly related to http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41652/how-can-i-lay-down-an-object-on-a-plane

Comment: But i don't think it'll work since i'm using a whole person with armatures. So if i use that instruction my person would just fall down. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: The question is not clear, then: if you rigged the "person", are you meaning that you wish to make it walk on a displaced ground plane or something?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i mean.

Comment: may this help you? http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?318857-Creating-a-walk-cycle-relative-to-the-ground but I feel your displaced floor complicates it...