# Rotate an Ico sphere with 20 sides(Icosahedron) to align with the level grid

Tags: objects

I'm just starting out with blender and I'm running into an issue. I'm trying to align one of the faces of my Ico sphere with 20 sides(Icosahedron) to be equal with the level grid. It doesn't matter which face. Basically I'm just trying to make a D20 sitting on a table.

Comment: You could also try using rigid body physics, related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41652/how-can-i-lay-down-an-object-on-a-plane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create your Icosphere
2. Add a new *Empty* object
3. Turn on Face Snapping
4. Turn on the *Align Rotation with Snapping Target* option
5. Move the Empty object and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while transforming to snap
6. Make it align to one of the desired faces
7. Afterwards select the Icosphere, then Shift-Select the Empty (so it stays the active object)
8. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to parent the Icosphere to the Empty
9. You can now move the empty freely wherever you want, and most importantly clear its rotation from the *Toolshelf* or with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
10. When correclty aligned unparent the Icosphere, and optionally apply its rotation if desired with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply > Rotation*

[image]

Comment: Wow that was way more complicated then I thought it would be but it worked like a charm. Thanks for the gif. It helped a lot.

Comment: Blender is unfortunately not very suited for this type of geometric precision modelling. It *can* do most stuff, it just requires a little more steps than one would like.