# Rotate object using reference point - exact rotation possible?

Tags: blend-modes

I need to rotate the object exact to be parallel to Y.
In my CAD I m used to use a reference point of the object I that I then can snap to an ax (or another snap-able geometry)
Is similar possible in blender - or how do I get the same result?

thanks for any help!

Florian

here the screenshot of the object:[image]

Comment: Related with some ways of doing it https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6369/how-to-align-an-object-by-one-or-two-edges-to-xyz-axes. This isn't one action in Blender as long as you have rotation applied / frozen.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80641/rotate-an-ico-sphere-with-20-sidesicosahedron-to-align-with-the-level-grid