# How do I calculate an angle of a surface?

Tags: modeling

I want to angle this cylinder to have the same angle as the top surface of this wedge.

How do I match the exact angle of the surface to the cylinder?

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80641/rotate-an-ico-sphere-with-20-sidesicosahedron-to-align-with-the-level-grid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you rotate an object so that a particular face is parallel to the ground?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56882/how-do-you-rotate-an-object-so-that-a-particular-face-is-parallel-to-the-ground)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides calculating the angle manually via trigonometry - you can actually snap and align objects to faces.

[image]

Turn on snaps, select face. Turn on Align rotation with the snapping target.

After you snap it, the angle should be displayed in the cylinder's transform.