# Align rotation with the snapping target, on a different axis?

Tags: faces, snapping, axis

I am stacking quite a few tall objects on uneven surfaces. To accomplish this I turn on `Snap during transform`, `Snap to Face`, `Closest` and `Align rotation with the snapping target`. This works fine, and my tall objects stand up-right on the surface. However, now I want some of these objects to lie down on the uneven surfaces. Is there a way to set what axis the Alignment is to follow? Instead of the bottom face of the object aligning to the surface (blue arrow up), have the right face align to the surface (red arrow right)?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80641/rotate-an-ico-sphere-with-20-sidesicosahedron-to-align-with-the-level-grid and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56882/how-do-you-rotate-an-object-so-that-a-particular-face-is-parallel-to-the-ground

Comment: Hm... Attach to a rotated Empty and snap the Empty sounds like a good idea. Thanks.